# Rails - Delayed Job of specific method with run_at in params / specifying when to post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I'm a bit at a loss here. 
I'm simply trying to delay a checkin, for instance, at a user defined time. I'd like to make it as simple as possible. 
***EDIT**: solved, see below.*

```
class MyController < ApplicationController

  def new_checkin
    # default venue is "SubMate"
    @venue_id = params[:venue_id] || "4c2c3acd8abca59355760120"
    @time = params[:time]
    @checkin = Delayed::Job.enqueue(self.perform_checkin, :run_at => @time.minutes.from_now)
  end

  def perform_checkin
    foursquare.checkins.add(:venueId => @venue_id, :broadcast => "private")
  end
```

The result is strange : the delayed_job is save, the action is performed (without the requested @time delay), and i still get an error:

```
ArgumentError in MyController#new_checkin
  Cannot enqueue items which do not respond to perform
```

What am I missing? How can I perform this delayed job, with the user requested delay?

Thank you!

**UPDATE** 
Thanks to @Roman below, didn't know you could pass arguments to delay:

```
def new_checkin
  @venue_id = params[:venue_id]
  @time = params[:time]
  @checkin = self.perform_checkin
end

def perform_checkin
  foursquare.checkins.delay({:run_at => @time.minutes.from_now}).add(:venueId => @venue_id, :broadcast => "private")
end
```

Comment: FYI, for us we passed `run_at` as the second param to `enqueue` and it worked great, like: `Delayed::Job.enqueue( job_to_run, run_at: 10.minutes.from_now )`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to enqueue it this way, then as the error suggests, the enqueued object should respond to :perform. Check this http://asciicasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job
You can also use :handle_asynchronously or .delay.method. Check this: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

Comment: Thanks Roman, i didn't know you could pass arguments to .delay - I updated my question (solved).